# Centering aligned blocks inside an equation

Tags: align

How to centre horizontally a group of aligned blocks, all inside a single numbered block?

Below, I'd like to centre the 1st line and the block containing the 2nd and 3rd ones.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath,amssymb,showframe}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        \begin{aligned}
        e_{0}^{2} &=  e_{0}, &
        e_{1}^{2} &= -e_{0}, &
        e_{2}^{2} &= -e_{0}, &
        e_{3}^{2} &= -e_{0},
        \end{aligned}\\
        \begin{aligned}
        e_{0}\cdot e_{1}=  e_{1}\cdot e_{0} &= e_{1}, &
        e_{0}\cdot e_{2}=  e_{2}\cdot e_{0} &= e_{2}, &
        e_{0}\cdot e_{3}=  e_{3}\cdot e_{0} &= e_{3},  \\
        e_{1}\cdot e_{2}= -e_{2}\cdot e_{1} &= e_{3}, &
        e_{2}\cdot e_{3}= -e_{3}\cdot e_{2} &= e_{1}, &
        e_{3}\cdot e_{1}= -e_{1}\cdot e_{3} &= e_{2}.
        \end{aligned}
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a `gathered` with a nested `aligned`; in the latter environment, I'd use the first `=` for setting the alignment, rather than the last.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath,amssymb,showframe}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{gathered}
  e_{0}^{2} = e_{0},\quad
  e_{1}^{2} = -e_{0},\quad
  e_{2}^{2} = -e_{0},\quad
  e_{3}^{2} = -e_{0},
\\
\begin{aligned}
  e_{0}\cdot e_{1} &=  e_{1}\cdot e_{0} = e_{1}, &
  e_{0}\cdot e_{2} &=  e_{2}\cdot e_{0} = e_{2}, &
  e_{0}\cdot e_{3} &=  e_{3}\cdot e_{0} = e_{3},  \\
  e_{1}\cdot e_{2} &= -e_{2}\cdot e_{1} = e_{3}, &
  e_{2}\cdot e_{3} &= -e_{3}\cdot e_{2} = e_{1}, &
  e_{3}\cdot e_{1} &= -e_{1}\cdot e_{3} = e_{2}.
\end{aligned}
\end{gathered}
\end{equation}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

The `\cdot` symbol seems superfluous, though.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath,amssymb,showframe}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{gathered}
  e_{0}^{2} = e_{0},\quad
  e_{1}^{2} = -e_{0},\quad
  e_{2}^{2} = -e_{0},\quad
  e_{3}^{2} = -e_{0},
\\
\begin{aligned}
  e_{0} e_{1} &=  e_{1} e_{0} = e_{1}, &
  e_{0} e_{2} &=  e_{2} e_{0} = e_{2}, &
  e_{0} e_{3} &=  e_{3} e_{0} = e_{3},  \\
  e_{1} e_{2} &= -e_{2} e_{1} = e_{3}, &
  e_{2} e_{3} &= -e_{3} e_{2} = e_{1}, &
  e_{3} e_{1} &= -e_{1} e_{3} = e_{2}.
\end{aligned}
\end{gathered}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. (off topic: the result of product is more important in this case so I decided to align on second `=`).

Comment: Is the `\quad` space used also by `align`? I mean, does the 1st line have the same output as the one from `align`?

Comment: @Sigur No, `aligned` works with the available space.

Answer (score 3):

not exactly as requested (no alignment), but might this be satisfactory?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{report}
%\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath,amssymb,showframe}
\usepackage{amsthm,mathtools,amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \begin{gathered}
        e_{0}^{2} =  e_{0}, \quad
        e_{1}^{2} = -e_{0}, \quad
        e_{2}^{2} = -e_{0}, \quad
        e_{3}^{2} = -e_{0}, \\
        e_{0}\cdot e_{1}=  e_{1}\cdot e_{0} = e_{1}, \quad
        e_{0}\cdot e_{2}=  e_{2}\cdot e_{0} = e_{2}, \quad
        e_{0}\cdot e_{3}=  e_{3}\cdot e_{0} = e_{3},  \\
        e_{1}\cdot e_{2}= -e_{2}\cdot e_{1} = e_{3}, \quad
        e_{2}\cdot e_{3}= -e_{3}\cdot e_{2} = e_{1}, \quad
        e_{3}\cdot e_{1}= -e_{1}\cdot e_{3} = e_{2}.
    \end{gathered}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

requires `mathtools` (for `gathered` environment), which loads `amsmath`.

Comment: Thanks. This will be good and useful to centre a lot of equations. But in my case, I need the alignment.